# Why doesn't the css `rotateY` property work on safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transforms

Below is my html and css code. It is pretty simple. I want to show a square `\F1FC` on a red react.

```css
.parent::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateY(-2deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

p::before {
  content: "\F1FC";
  color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

This code works fine on chrome but doesn't work on safari. Half of the square is hidden by the `p::before`. Below is a screen shot on safari:

[image]

Below is the screenshot for chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some kind of weird bug in Safari and pseudo elements. My solution for this issue was to counter the `transform: rotateY(-2deg);` on the parent pseudo element since it was causing the issue.

Add `display: block;` and `transform: rotateY(1deg);` to `p::before`. The small rotation doesn't seem to affect how the square looks and it fixes it for me in Safari.

```css
.parent::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateY(-2deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

p::before {
  content: "\F1FC";
  color: black;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  transform: rotateY(1deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p></p>
</div>
```